# Exact difference between the wordpress address url and the site address url

Tags: wordpress

I am currently fixing a wordpress theme that contains absolute URLs. Example:

```
$.preloadImages('/wp-content/themes/themeName/img/button.png');
```

Now I want to prefix the url with something like `WP_HOME` or `WP_SITEURL` but I don't know which one to choose. What is the exact difference? In other words, what is the scenario in which the two might differ?

I guess they correspond to the "wordpress address" and the "site address" in the settings. However, the explanation there does not help me.

Comment: so actually you want to know about theme url and theme directory url right?

Comment: Not exactly, please refer to the accepted answer and the comment below it. However, I also learned something new from your answer, so I upvoted it, too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use neither. Use a function instead of a constant `get_bloginfo('url');` or `get_bloginfo('wpurl');`. If you have your `wp-content` inside of the wordpress install it does not really matter (but I prefer the first).

Take a look at the following functions: [`content_url()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/content_url), [`get_template_directory_uri()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_template_directory_uri/) (for parent themes) or [`get_stylesheet_directory_uri()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_stylesheet_directory_uri/) (for themes including child themes). When using these functions you don't rely on one particular directory structure.

In your case I'd use

```
trailingslashit(get_stylesheet_directory_uri()) . 'img/button.png';
```

**EDIT**

`WP_SITEURL` is your WordPress address (`wp_url`) and WP_HOME is your blog address (`url`). By default the `wp-content` directory is a sibling to `wp-admin` and `wp-includes` and both constants have the same value but you move it out of there and make use of the `WP_CONTENT_FOLDERNAME`, `WP_CONTENT_DIR` and `WP_CONTENT_URL` constant to move it somewhere else, e.g.

```
wp-content
index.php
wordpress
  |-- wp-admin
  |-- wp-includes
```

now `WP_SITEURL` will return `https://yourdomain.com/wordpress/` and `WP_HOME` will be `https://yourdomain.com/`, see https://codex.wordpress.org/Giving_WordPress_Its_Own_Directory for more details of giving WordPress its own directory.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I think this will solve my current problem. However, I haven't understood how the URLs are different. Can you please extend your answer to include this? Where is the `wp-content` directory supposed to live? Below the wordpress address or the site address?

Comment: Thanks, now I got it.

Answer (score 1):

```
href="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/img/button.png"
```

so use  get_template_directory_uri()

**DIFFERANCE**

**1. [get_template_directory();](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_template_directory)**

```
<?php echo get_template_directory(); ?>
```

Returns an absolute server path (eg: /home/user/public_html/wp-content/themes/my_theme), not a URI.

**2.[get_template_directory_uri](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_template_directory_uri/) ()**

Retrieve theme directory URI.

www.example.com/wp-content/theme/themename/image/image.png

**AS per your query. if its for plugin then use `plugin_url` or for theme  `get_template_directory_uri()`**

```
get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/custom-script.js'
```

Here are other functions.

**SITE URL** 
the `site_url` template tag retrieves the site url for the current site (where the WordPress core files reside) with the appropriate protocol, '`https`' `if is_ssl()` and '`http`' otherwise. If scheme is '`http`' or '`https`', `is_ssl()` is overridden.

**Use this to get** the "WordPress address" as defined in general settings. Use `home_url()` to get the "site address" as defined in general settings.

```
$url = site_url();
echo $url;
```

Output: http://www.example.com or http://www.example.com/wordpress

**HOME URL**

The `home_url` template tag retrieves the home URL for the current site, optionally with the $path argument appended. The function determines the appropriate protocol,

```
 $url = home_url();
echo $url;
```

Output: http://www.example.com

So mostly both are similar. not different. you cal also use / in both to get / in output.

**BLOG INFO**

There is another one is blog info

```
function bloginfo( $show='' ) {
    echo get_bloginfo( $show, 'display' );
}
<?php bloginfo('url'); ?> it will also return blog url .
```

Answer (score 1):

home_url : Its your Home URL for your site.

site_url : Where your wordpress Core files are located.

For your use you can use site_url this will work for you.